# JsonCpp how to std::sort a Json::Value that is an array

Tags: c++, json, sorting, jsoncpp

I would like to sort an Json::Value that is an array (of dicts) using something similar to std::sort(), but I get errors when trying to make the custom sort function like this:

```
bool sort_json_array(Json::Value a, Json::Value b)
{
    return a["some_double_member"].asDouble() > b["some_double_member"].asDouble();
}
```

I am calling std::sort as follows:

```
std::sort(json_array.begin(), json_array.end(), sort_json_array);
```

But this gives some errors that I don't understand, all are similar to:

```
no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘Json::ValueIterator’ and ‘int’)
```

How can I sort the Json array?

Comment: `Json::ValueIterator` doesn't meet `RandomAccessIterator` requirement needed for `std::sort`.

Comment: Oh thank you Jarod42. That is too bad. I guess the option then is to iterate through the Json array, put all elements into a new vector, then std::sort the vector... Unless anyone has a better idea I will try this.

Comment: BTW, your `sort_json_array` would take their argument by *const ref*.

Comment: You can just push them into a new sorted array(insert them in order) as you iterate through...no need to copy twice...

Comment: Ah yes const ref is better. Benjamin, I will keep that in mind next time, but in the case of my program, the sort will only happen once during the program's lifetime, so an extra copy is okay with me since the code works now, and the array is small.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I chose was to make a new empty vector, then iterate over the Json array, inserting each element into the vector. Then I std::sort()ed the vector using the sort_json_array() from the question above (except I changed it to take const references as suggested by Jarod42). Thanks for the help folks!